# HTML bridge fails when running JavaFX 11 app after jlink was used to create distribution

Tags: java, javafx

Having a hybrid JavaFx 11 / HTML app.

I have a HTML link somewhere in a webview, which is connected to a Java class as seen below.

```
<a href="#" onclick=\"HelpView.fabricbinaries()">
```

Is supposed to be automatically connected to

```
public class HelpView extends HtmlView {

    public void fabricbinaries() {
        try {
            Desktop.openWebpage(new URL(Chaincoder4.getDownloadLinkBinaryFabric()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.error(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

But nothing happens when I click on those link. I have tried to find out about error messages. But had no success so far.

All links not only this one work fine when I run my app within the IDE before jlink was used. Thanks for your help.

```
jlink --module-path /Users/.../target:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/jmods:/Users/.../javafx-jmods-11.0.2 --add-modules chaincoder,java.base,java.desktop,javafx.web,jdk.jsobject --launcher chaincoder=chaincoder/core.Main --output /Users/.../dist
```

Comment: It will help if you post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I did additional tests and I can confirm that javascript within the webview works and a plain html link without java bridge works as well.

Comment: I did find the solution after reading the official webengine documentation. The problem is related to modules which must allow reflections.

Comment: Deploying an Application as a Module

If any Java class passed to JavaScript is in a named module, then it must be reflectively accessible to the javafx.web module. A class is reflectively accessible if the module opens the containing package to at least the javafx.web module. Otherwise, the method will not be called, and no error or warning will be produced.

For example, if com.foo.MyClass is in the foo.app module, the module-info.java might look like this:

module foo.app {
    opens com.foo to javafx.web;
}